# Calculate Number of distinct transaction id that has been delivered in a particular month

Tags: tableau-api

The formula used for calculating is

```
IF (NOT ISNULL(ATTR([Order Delivered Date])))
 THEN COUNTD([Transaction Id])
ELSE 0 
ENDL
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ENDL` to `END`

```
 IF (NOT ISNULL(ATTR([Order Delivered Date])))
      THEN COUNTD([Transaction Id])
 ELSE 0 
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
countd(if not isnull([Order Delivered Date]) then [Transaction Id] end)
```

using the filter shelf or another shelf such as row or columns, to apply the formula to jus the month (or other period) of interest

Answer (score 0):

Use ->

```
If not isnull([Order Delivered Date]) then
[Transaction Id]
Else
0
End
```

Drag and drop this field in you desired mark then mark the calculation as CountD.
This will give you the distinct count for a particular month.
Let me know if this helps.